# Triple Commas not acceptable?

Tags: american-english, commas, comma-splices

I'm wondering why this phrasing:

> I spend most days thinking about the future. Hoping that I'm on the right path, I do my best at everything I can.

is preferred over this one:

> I spend most days thinking about the future, hoping that I'm on the right path, I do my best at everything I can.

I ***think*** both are grammatically correct (I'm not so sure about the latter). In my ACT textbook, it says that the latter is indeed grammatically incorrect.

But—we are allowed to use commas to insert additional information. For example:

> Her brother, who lives in Chicago, came to see her.

So, I am not sure why the latter is deemed incorrect.

Comment: In the second sentence, it is unclear to which side the middle bit belongs.  Do you spend most days thinking about the future and hoping that you're on the right path?  Or do you do the best at everything you can while hoping that you're on the right path?  It's two independent clauses fused together strangely.

Comment: Your question title mentions "triple commas", but there are only two commas in the examples you are asking about. Perhaps you meant *double* commas? In any case, as others have said, it's not the number of commas at issue – it's the structure of the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example is grammatically incorrect, but the problem is not the number of commas.

"I spend most days ... doing" is OK:

> I spend most days thinking about the future, hoping that I'm on the right path, and doing my best at everything I can.

It means:

"I spend time

- thinking,
- hoping, and
- doing"

but "I spend most days .... I do" (as in your second example) is not ok. It means

"I spend time

- thinking,
- hoping, and
- I do".

"I do" is not a way that you can "spend most days". You have to spend time "do*ing*".

The verb "to do" needs to be in the [present continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_continuous_(English)) (as in "I am doing") rather than the [simple present](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_present) (as in "I do") - as "hoping" and "thinking" already are.

Answer (score 0):

The second sample is grammatically incorrect, not because of the number of commas, but because one of the commas is joining two sentences. I say that there are two sentences because *I spend…* forms a sentence, and *I do…* forms another one. (Each one has a subject and a verb.)

There are valid ways to form a sentence consisting of sentences:

- use punctuation (such as a semicolon, colon, em dash, or double quote)
- use a conjunction (such as *and*, *or*, *but*, *while*, *because*, or *that*)

However a comma is not among the valid way to join two sentences to form a sentence. Doing so is a grammatical error called a **comma splice**.

---

In the last example, *who lives in Chicago* is not a complete sentence, but a [relative clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause), which is allowable.